# PHP - enclose <ul> tag with <div> using regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an html string like below.

```
<ul style="margin-left: 240px;">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Three
        <ul>
            <li>dfdf</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>dfds</li>
</ul>
```

I want to enclose the `<ul>` tag with a `<div>` with style of `<ul>`

```
<div style="margin-left: 240px;">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Three
            <ul>
                <li>dfdf</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>dfds</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried with following `regex`, but it is not working with nested `<ul>`.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<ul(.*?)>(.*?)<\/ul>/s', '<div $1><ul>$2</ul></div>', $html);
```

It is finding the string between first `<ul>` open and second `</ul>` close. I will have multiple `<ul>` structure with in the same string

Please help me to write the correct regular expression for this.

Comment: I would recommend manipulating the DOM with [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or a library rather than trying to solve this with RegEx..

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not strictly powerful enough to handle nesting. Instead, try using an appropriate XML or HTML parser, manipulating the parsed structure, and rendering it back to a string.

Comment: it would match correctly any correct formated html, just as any html parser, the downsides are the performance and work needed to achieve the same things since it wasn't developed with concern to html parsing

Comment: @Breezer: I maintain that regular expressions formally do not have the power to match nested tags. To match languages with arbitrarily deep nesting, you need a context-free grammar. See the [Chomsky language hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$html = preg_replace('/<ul (.*?)>(.+)</ul>/gs', '<div $1><ul>$2</ul></div>', $html);
```

Comment: `<ul id="first-list"><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul> other stuff <ul id="second-list"><li>c</li><li>d</li></ul>` Oops!

Comment: Its okay. Author wants to replace only first <ul>. But inside he has another <ul>'s, that should not be touched. And its works on your example too.

Comment: If there was only one `ul` and that's all the string consisted of, there would be scant need for a regular expression at all; if not for transferring the attributes to the `div`, you might just prepend and append the `div` open and closing tags. We're then up to three solutions: 1. concatenating, which works for a single `ul` tag and no surrounding content; 2. your solution, which still only works for a single `ul` tag but does deal with some surrounding content; and 3. my solution, which can handle any number of `ul` tags and any amount of surrounding content.

Comment: Your solution does indeed work for the case where you have some surrounding content which does not contain any `ul` tags, but that seems a very limited case. While the example the question includes does fit that case (or indeed, a special case of it where there is no surrounding content), I'm not sure the person who asked the question would be satisfied with a solution with such limited applicability.